# Python Dictionary and list confusion

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Hi I am trying to learn dicts and list in Python.
My code:

```
wardrobe = {"shirt":["red","blue","white"], "jeans":["blue","black"]}
for clothes in wardrobe.values():
    for colors in wardrobe.keys():
        print("{}{}".format(clothes (colors) ))
```

My result should be "red shirt", "blue shirt", and so on...
My error code is :
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Kindly help with simple description

Comment: Take it one step at a time. See what you get if you print "clothes".

Comment: `clothes (colors)` tries to call `clothes` as a function. You probably want `clothes, colors` there.

Comment: for clothes in wardrobe  (and not .values())

Comment: You also got it backwards: `wardrobe.values()` are the lists of colors, `wardrobe.keys()` are the clothes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you meant to do:

```
wardrobe = {"shirt":["red","blue","white"], "jeans":["blue","black"]}

for cloth, colors in wardrobe.items():
    for color in colors:
        print("{} {}".format(color, cloth))
```

Comment: Right, but that's just one out of three (or five) problems.

Comment: @tobias_k yes sir! I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're trying to do:

```
wardrobe = {"shirt":["red","blue","white"], "jeans":["blue","black"]}
for clothes in wardrobe:
    for colors in wardrobe[clothes]:
        print("{} {}".format(colors,clothes))
```

Output:

```
red shirt
blue shirt
white shirt
blue jeans
black jeans
```